# Node FS module throws ENOENT Error When Trying To Use Watch Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, fs

***I am using macOS 10.13.4 and Node version 8.11.4.*** I am trying to follow a simple tutorial from tutsplus.com called [Node From Scratch](https://code.tutsplus.com/courses/nodejs-from-scratch/lessons/the-event-loop-and-async-programming) . The second video in starts off with requiring the **FS** module and then calling the **watch** method on a file to watch for changes to the file.

```
'use strict';

const fs = require( 'fs' );

fs.watch( 'stylesheet.css', () => console.log( 'File Has Been Updated' ) );

console.log( "Application Has Started And Is Listening For Changes" );
```

Whenever I attempt to run the js file in the terminal using Node I get the error

```
fs.js:1384
throw error;
^
Error: watch stylesheet.css ENOENT
at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1382:19)
at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1408:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Downloads/filewatcher.js:5:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
```

I can't seem to find anything online about why this is happening. Can anyone please help.

Comment: do you have a file called stylesheet.css?

Comment: @ashishsingh yes I do

Comment: i am not sure then, kindly check the spelling once and it should be in same directory as that of this js file

Comment: @ashishsingh thank you, yeah I have checked the spelling, and it is in the same directory, and I am still having no luck.

Comment: oh if you are not a beginner and you can read the file can you do one experiment to read a file in similar location ;  name it b.css  and try to read it.. so that you know your setup is correct

Comment: @ashishsingh calling the readFile method on the FS module on the same stylesheet.css file in the same directory throws the error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'stylesheet.css'

Comment: create one more file and type the name yourself as `a.txt` and try to read it

Comment: @ashishsingh still the same thing. It's obviously there, I can see it and I just created it. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'a.txt' .

Comment: Try '. /a.txt' as filepath

Comment: @ashishsingh so i just figured it out, it is attempting to find the file in my root user path instead of using the current directory that the JS file I am running in node is in. So if I specify the full path to the file it works. Any idea why this is happening or how to resolve this?

Comment: did you try './a.txt'

Comment: where did you run your node command ?

Comment: @ashishsingh i just opened the terminal and called the node command, then i specified the directory for where the JS file to run is located. So i'm assuming I need to CD into the directory where I am going to run node?

Comment: if you are running from some custom location, you will face this issue.. and you will have to take care of paths your self

Comment: when you opened the terminal it might have the current directory as user directory and thats why it was looking there

Comment: did you try `./stylesheet.css`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have noted, you're having trouble with absolute vs relative paths and how node handles the current working directory.

The crux of your issue is best demonstrated by running the following:

```
const path = require('path');
console.log(path.resolve('foo'));
console.log(path.resolve('./foo'));
```

In the latter case, node resolves the relative path against the current working directory of the node process. The cwd can be confirmed using:

```
console.log(process.cwd());
```

The cwd of the node process is determined from where you call node.

For example, if you have the following file structure:

```
/
└──projects/
   └──app/
      ├──js/
      │  └──dep.js
      ├──index.js
      └──test.txt
```

index.js contents:

```
const fs = require('fs');
console.log(process.cwd());
console.log(fs.readFileSync('./test.txt'));
require('./js/dep.js');
```

dep.js contents:

```
const fs = require('fs');
console.log(process.cwd());
console.log(fs.readFileSync('./test.txt'));
```

If you navigated to `/projects/app` and ran `node index.js` you would see the program successfully print the cwd and the contents of test.txt twice. This demonstrates how the cwd is consistent across the different source files the program uses.

If you navigated to `/app` and ran `node app/index.js` you would see the program crash with the ENOENT error. This demonstrates how starting your program from different locations changes the cwd.